# UITapGesture and TouchesBegan are producing different locations in view

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uitapgesturerecognizer, gamekit, touchesbegan

I'm using **SKTileMaps** and a **CameraNode** as well as **GameplayKit** and **SpriteKit**

The code I want to work **is incorrectly** finding a location in the "view"

```
func handleTapFrom(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let location = sender.location(in: self.view)
    if (map.contains(location))
    {
        let tRow = map.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: location)
        let tColumn = map.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: location)
        let movePosition = map.centerOfTile(atColumn: tColumn, row: tRow)
        let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: movePosition, duration:1.0)
        cam.run(moveAction)
    }

}
```

and the code that **is working correctly** is finding locations in self (rather than self.view) and this is correct

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) 
{
    let firstTouch = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    if (map.contains(firstTouch!))
    {
        let tRow = map.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: firstTouch!)
        let tColumn = map.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: firstTouch!)
        let movePosition = map.centerOfTile(atColumn: tColumn, row: tRow)
        let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: movePosition, duration:1.0)
        cam.run(moveAction)
    }
}
```

**The columns and rows are correct based on the location, the problem I am having is that the locations (xfloat, yfloat) are different between the two functions even when the touch is at the same location**

These two bits of code are all in the class GameScene, but I cannot figure out why they have different locations? And how to fix the tap gesture so that the locations it finds are the same as those found in touchesBegan.

Sorry if this is confusing or unintelligible. I welcome an opportunity to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `handleTapFrom` function the location should come from `convertPoint`.

```
func handleTapFrom(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state != .ended {
        return
    }

    let location = sender.location(in: sender.view!)
    let targetLocation = self.convertPoint(fromView: location)

    if map.contains(targetLocation) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```